# Event declarations

Tags: ruby

I got the following code from @avdi's Ruby Tapas episode for today:

```
module Eventful
  def self.included(other)
    other.extend(Macros)
  end
  def add_listener(listener)
    (@listeners ||= []) << listener
  end
  def notify_listeners(event, *args)
    (@listeners || []).each do |listener|
      listener.public_send("on_#{event}", *args)
    end
  end

  module Macros
    def event(name)
      module_eval(%Q{
        def #{name}(*args)
          notify_listeners(:#{name}, *args)
        end
      })
    end
  end
end

class Dradis
  include Eventful
  event :new_contact
end

class ConsoleListener
  def on_new_contact(direction, range)
    puts "DRADIS contact! #{range} kilometers, bearing #{direction}"
  end
end

dradis = Dradis.new
dradis.add_listener(ConsoleListener.new)
dradis.new_contact(120, 23000)
```

I understand the concept of events and listeners and the observer pattern, but don't get how/why this syntax is working, and haven't seen it in any manuals. The class `Dradis` has this:

```
 event :new_contact
```

At first, I thought that `event` was a method and `:new_contact` was an argument so that I would call `event` on an instance of `Dradis`, something like:

```
dradis = Dradis.new
dradis.event
```

but instead, `new_contact` is called on an instance of `Dradis` like:

```
dradis = Dradis.new
dradis.add_listener(ConsoleListener.new)
dradis.new_contact(120, 23000)
```

and that triggers the `event` method in the Macro module.

Can anyone explain why it works like this? calling `:new_contact` on an instance `dradis` to trigger the event method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't watch the episode, but look, it's right there.

```
  module Macros
    def event(name)
      module_eval(%Q{
        def #{name}(*args)
          notify_listeners(:#{name}, *args)
        end
      })
    end
  end
```

`event` is a method which defines another method (`new_contact`) which calls `notify_listeners` from `Eventful`.

> and that triggers the event method in the Macro module

Incorrect. That method has finished its work a long time ago and it doesn't get invoked again. It produced a new method using `module_eval` / `def` and that new method (`new_contact`) is what's getting called.

It's important to understand that `event` method runs only once, when the `Dradis` class is parsed and loaded. It does not get run on every instantiation of `Dradis`.

Comment: thanks, so does event :new_method get called on the instantiation of the Dradis class Dradis.new? how does event get called?

Comment: No, it gets called when Dradis class is parsed and loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Several separated features of ruby is used: In the line `event :new_contact` the "evnet" is class method (http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#UE).

Usually class methods are defined by:

```
  class A
    def A.my_class_method
     #code
    end
  end
  A.my_class_method #executing class_method
```

or

```
  class A
    def <<self   #usefull when you want delare several class methods
      def A.my_class_method
        #code
      end
    end
  end
  A.my_class_method #executing class_method
```

In the code the method is included by the module `Macros`.

The key thing is, that (class method) `event` is dynamicaly creating new (instance) method (in this case `new_contact`)
The name of the method is passed as argument to `event`). And this method providing calling of the listener.

> Can anyone explain why it works like this? calling :new_contact on an instance dradis to trigger the event method?

This is by the dynammically created method `new_contact` which is calling `notify_listeners(:#{name}, *args)`